# Cross check files in two folders

Tags: vbscript, match, filenames

I have two folders: Master folder & New folder. Files in two folders share the same file name. I need to cross check the files between these two folders.

- If Master folder does not have the file, I import it from New folder.
- If Master folder does have the file, I append the master file with the data in new file.

With the code below, I can append data. But it fails to import file. The script shows no error message. I just don't know what went wrong.

```
On Error Resume Next
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set SrcFolder = fso.GetFolder("C:\Users\Vault Keeper\Desktop\NewFile")
DestFolder = "C:\Users\Vault Keeper\Desktop\MasterFile"

For Each NewFile in SrcFolder.files
    If fso.FileExists(DestFolder & "\" & NewFile.name) Then
        txt = NewFile.OpenAsTextStream(1).ReadAll
        Set MasterFile = FSO.OpenTextFile(DestFolder & "\" & NewFile.name, 8)
        MasterFile.Write txt
    Else
        fso.CopyFile "C:\Users\Vault Keeper\Desktop\NewFile" & "\" & NewFile.name, _
            DestFolder
    End If
Next
```

Comment: Are you sure you are trying to use VBA? I think you mean VBS.

Comment: Basically you are performing a mirror from **New folder** to **Master folder**? If so, use **robocopy**, it allows you to log changes.

Comment: Thank you Patrick for pointing out that. I extracted part of my code to illustrate the problem. Robocopy seems not the right thing for me. As I am not backing up files. Rather I am updating the data of the master folder which is read by another third party software.

Comment: I can maunally copy and paste data. But file numbers are so large and the work is so routine that I want to automate the process.

Comment: Given that you want to automate as much as possible, you can do a batch file with robocopy and schedule this batch file in Task scheduler. Robocopy can be used to copy updated files, not just mirroring. You can apply file filters too. With a VBS file, you still need to use a batch file with cscript for task scheduling. You can write hundred lines of code to accomplish something less feature than robocopy.

Comment: What do you mean by **append** to the one in Master folder?

Comment: That's not what I am aware of. I think I will google more on robocopy. Thanks PatricK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's rather unsurprising that you don't know what went wrong when you tell your script to shut up about whatever's going wrong (`On Error Resume Next`). Remove that line (using global OERN is a terrible practice anyway) and see what error you get.

Most likely the error is "permission denied", because you're trying to copy a file to an existing destination folder without that path ending with a backslash:

```
DestFolder = "C:\Users\Vault Keeper\Desktop\MasterFile"   '<-- no trailing backslash
...
fso.CopyFile "C:\Users\Vault Keeper\Desktop\NewFile" & "\" & NewFile.name, DestFolder
```

Quoting from the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e1wf9e7w%28v=vs.84%29.aspx):

> If *source* contains wildcard characters or *destination* ends with a path separator (), it is assumed that *destination* is an existing folder in which to copy matching files. Otherwise, *destination* is assumed to be the name of a file to create. In either case, three things can happen when an individual file is copied.
>
> - If *destination* does not exist, *source* gets copied. This is the usual case.
> - If *destination* is an existing file, an error occurs if *overwrite* is **false**. Otherwise, an attempt is made to copy *source* over the existing file.
> - If *destination* is a directory, an error occurs.

Append a backslash to the destination path, and the error should vanish. Also, since you already have a [`File`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1ft05taf%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) object, I'd recommend to use its [`Copy`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6973t06a%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) method rather than `CopyFile`:

```
NewFile.Copy DestFolder & "\"
```

Comment: You nail it! This is exactly what I want. I learnt vbs through trial and error, not building up from ground zero. So sometimes I might miss the meaning of some lines. You just save me hours to dig deep in google. Thank you Ansgar Wiechers.

Answer (score 0):

You can check file using this

```
Dim objFSO As Scripting.FileSystemObject

If objFSO Is Nothing Then Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

If objFSO.FileExists(fileNameAndPath) Then
    'code here...
End If
```

Comment: Thank you san-san. Is there a way to duplicate the file if it does not exist in Master folder?

Comment: You could copy the file from one folder to another
    
    *objFSO.CopyFile Source:=FromPath, Destination:=ToPath*